Why do I get a 404 error after updating my PHP website to HTTPS?
I have updated my PHP website from HTTP to HTTPS. Of course, I've updated the URL in code and I've fixed several errors like mixed URLs.
But I am always redirected to the 404 page error, so I've removed temporally my whole website code to do it as easy as I can and test it better.
Now, here is my index.php file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="My description."/>
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="XXXXX"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != "") {
                echo("GET: ".isset($_GET['lang']));
            } else {
                echo('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www.mywebsite.com/en">');
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>

And this is my .htaccess file:
Options All -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&menu=$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9ÑñÇçÜüÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú=_-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&menu=$2&page=$3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9ÑñÇçÜüÁáÉéÍíÓóÚú=_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&menu=$2&page=$3&key=$4
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/404-page-htaccess.php

When I load on the URL https://mywebsite.com, I am redirected to https://mywebsite.com/en, which is OK, but it returns the content of 404-page-htaccess.php since it gets a 404 error.
To be honest, I don't remember much about PHP and this website, but can anyone tell me what could be happening?
First I had tried with PHP header("Location: ..."); to do the redirection, with same result. I also tried lots of things with no result.
BTW: If I replace the redirection line to echo('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=index.php?lang=en">');, it works OK, but the URL is not clean and that's not what I want.

First of all, a RewriteCond only affects the immediately following rule. If you want to apply that condition to all rules - then you need to repeat it before each one of them.

Second, I would rather handle the "missing language" redirect via mod_rewrite as well, rather than do it from within the application code. (But that's a matter of opinion, up to you.) Can't really see how it goes wrong with what you currently have though. Your RewriteCond checks if no file with the name en exists on the root level - but do you have a folder by that name there, perhaps? (Although then you should still not get a 404 response, I suppose.)

Regarding your first comment, I've modified the .htaccess file like above, to apply the RewriteCondto all rules. Regarding your second comment, there is no file named en on the root level. What more could I check?

You have a single router file right now, and "magic" happens in htaccess to set some specific query string variables. Since you are 95% of the way there already, I'd personally recommend going all-in on the single router. Instead of writing rules that can be hard to debug in htaccess, you could inspect and parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in your router and do whatever you need: https://3v4l.org/mX5Pr. There is a small performance gain by doing this in htaccess, but I would be surprised if you would notice it, and I think that the ability to debug out-weighs it. You didn't ask for this, I know.

You can enable rewrite logging to see what exactly is happening internally, in more detail.

When I check the access.log file, I see "GET /en HTTP/1.1" 404 3673 www.mywebsite.com "https://mywebsite.com/" ... "GET /en HTTP/1.1" 404 3673 mywebsite.com "https://mywebsite.com/" ... It seems to look for a directory named "/en" instead of executing first the .htaccess rule RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 and going to the index.php. Is this true right?

I've found a way to fix the website: adding a / before the destination files in the rules of the .htaccess file.
I had this:
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1

And I changed it to this:
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1

Do you find any sense on doing this? The website worked perfectly without the initial / when it was accessed by HTTP...
